# Placing a bypass capacitor on an LCD w/built-in serial controller a good idea?

Tags: capacitor, lcd, bypass

I'm trying to learn more about bypass capacitors and am wondering whether an LCD that I have should have a bypass capacitor or not. I have an LCD that uses a built-in controller, a PIC16F690 for serial communication. I'm aware of the general rule of thumb that an integrated circuit requires at least one bypass capacitor. I'm not sure if my LCD that has a built-in controller falls under this category. I'm also not sure whether or not LCD's in general are considered integrated circuits. I'm able to operate the LCD just fine without any bypass capacitor. The data sheet for the LCD makes no mention of needing a bypass capacitor. Would it be a good idea to place a bypass capacitor anyway?

The data sheet for LCD in question: http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-0216K3Z-FL-GBW.pdf

Comment: Can you see whether it already has one built in? I suspect it does. Also, are you familiar with why bypass capacitors close to the IC power pins are required?

Comment: I see that it has one built in now. Thank you for pointing that out. My understanding is that bypass caps are placed to ensure that a steady voltage at the power pin is maintained when there are fluctuations in the power supply. Smaller capacitors help with fast fluctuations while larger capacitors help with slower fluctuations. Is that right? My understanding might not be perfect so I would appreciate any further input.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any bypass capacitor.And you don't confuse the bypass capacitors and a stabilizing capacitor(capacitor connected parallel with power supply).Bypass capacitors are generally used in amplifier circuits.Basically,to provide a low resistance path for an AC signal,bypass capacitors are used.

  From the capacitor impedance z=1/(2*pi
  *f*
  C),you can notice that ,if frequency increases,impedance decreases.In general,they're used inbetween the input and output for low resistance path.

  But the stabilizing capacitor is used to maintain the voltage almost constantly and reject the sudden changes occur in the power supply unit,so that you're LCD will be safe for peak shoots of voltages.

  So you don't need to use a bypass capacitor,but you can use stabilizing capacitor